# How does Bing get away with showing Youtube videos on its own site?

Tags: copyright

Bing shows Youtube videos directly on its own page instead of sending the traffic to Youtube. How do they get away with copyright etc? Do you have legal support by only writing who uploaded it and linking to the source?

I assume that Bing is a competing business to Youtube and if Youtube could have, they would have forced Bing to send over the traffic.

Comment: It looks like they are just embedding the youtube player the same way anyone can, as a specifically allowed  use. Or are you talking about something else?

Answer (score 1):

### Because they have YouTube's permission

While the above is speculation, it is highly likely that Microsoft (owners of Bing) and Google (owners of YouTube) have negotiated a commercial agreement that is different from the agreement they offer to just anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you speculating like me or are: "Because they have YouTube's permission" true facts?

Comment: See the bit where I say it’s speculation- that means I’m speculating

Comment: "While the above is speculation" I see what you're writing but i'm also above so it got confusing :)